# Поиск текста в файлах и копирование его в edit1-n на Delphi7

Tags: поисковые-системы

Доброго времени суток, нужна помощь в программирование на Delphi7. Проблема заключается в том что мне надо написать программу которая будет искать определённый текст в файлах, после чего копировать и вставлять его в нужные поля (edit1-n).
К примеру:

<NAME> **Вася** </NAME>

нужно найти в тексте "Вася" после скопировать его в Edit1 и так дальше....

Comment: @AlexRA_13, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярки. Например вот [тут](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) (класс не проверял) взять класс для работы с регулярками и ползать по файлам выдирая всё что нужно. Проще конечно в C# это сделать, там регулярки родные, да и с файловой системой попроще работать, но раз уж Delphi так Delphi.